# What's up with this flagging menu?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/46519/23061) with the reason "This looks like brainstorming/idea gathering..." since I can't vote to close yet.

Weirdly, when I opened up the flagging menu again (I can't remember why) both the "closed for another" reason option *and* the "it is a duplicate" option were disabled, both with a warning saying I have raised this type of flag already. You can see this in the image below.

[image: Flagging menu in question]

What's up with this behavior? Are both supposed to be disabled for some reason? If so, shouldn't the option I *didn't* click have a different warning?

Answer (score 3):

I believe a few of the flags count as a flag to possibly close... thus disabling the other "close reason" flags (duplicate is a close reason as well).

In fact, I *think* only the "low quality" may *not* be considered a close reason.

.. just guessing here.

Comment: I think Spam flag is probably also different, especially as it contributes to higher spam blocking function.

Comment: Shouldn't it say some other warning if this is the case?

Comment: Yup. The logic is that a close vote is just a certain type of flag (sorta) (or maybe the other way around) so if you've voted to close, then you've already flagged to close.

Comment: Terrible UI, though. No disputing that.